# None of the arguments can be called with the agruments supplied with Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, kotlin-multiplatform

I have started working with a Kotlin Multiplatform library, and I make use of `Gson` on the android side to do some processes. Since I know iOS does not have support for Gson, I decided to create an `expected` function called `convertToJson` which has a return type of a class. However when I have the `actual` implementation, I get the following error:

> `None of the arguments can be called with the arguments supplied`

This occurs at this line of code:

```
actual fun convertFromJson(json:String): ClassName {
    return Gson().fromJson(json, ClassName::class) // this is where the error lies
}
```

I also have an `actual` implementation of a function called `convertToJson` which does not give me an error, so I am wondering why the above mentioned `convertFromJson` function gives me an error.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gson` is implemented in java and its `fromJson` accepts an instance of `java.lang.Class` as the argument, so you should replace `ClassName::class` with `ClassName::class.java`, because the former gives you an instance of `kotlin.reflect.KClass`.

Comment: Aah that makes sense. Thank you for your time and explanation. Very helpful